# Send objects array to php with ajax and submit to SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to create an nestable list which I can reorder by drag and drop and are doing very well up til now, thank yo very much ;-), but...

Everything is working as it should but I want to be able to save tor order into the db through php when I drop an item but am not sure how to do so?

When I drop an item I get an array of objects like this:

*[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]*

Each object and item and a itemId:

```
<li data-item="<?=$row['name']?>" data-item-id="<?=$row['fk_module_id']?>">
```

How do I pass this to php through ajax and how do I open the objects in the php script?

Here is the jQuery that handles the dragDrop part:

```
$("#modules-active").on('nestable-stop', function(ev)
{
    var serialized = $(this).data('nestable').serialize(),
    str = '';

    console.log( serialized );
    console.log( $(this).data('nestable').list() );

    $.post( "savelist.php", { list: serialized }).done(function( data ) { 

    });

});
```

To recap: How do I pass this correctly to php and how do I open and save it on the php page?

any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `serialize()` can only act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` and not on list items!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li class='data' data-item="<?=$row['name']?>" data-item-id="<?=$row['fk_module_id']?>">


jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    url = " Your php file url/savelist.php";
    var allVals = [];
    $('.btn').click(function(){

        $('.data').each(function() {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.post(url,{ array : allVals }, function(response,status){

            if(status == 'success'){

                //ur stuffs
                return status;
            }
        })
    })

})
```

it may help u ..